# chrome profile not opening by puppeteer

Tags: node.js, windows, puppeteer

**when I'm running this code**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
  console.log("Launching the browser...");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    userDataDir:
      "C:\\Users\\ABUL.HASAN\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1",
  });
  console.log("Opening a new page for video navigation...");
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log("New page for video navigation opened successfully.");
  console.log("Navigating to the desired URL...");
  await page.goto("https://www.example.com/", {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });
})();
```

It is opening a new Chrome instance and that too in guest mode even though I have mentioned profile.
I'm using

windows 10
Node.js v20.9.0
puppeteer 21.10.0 
chrome 121.0.6167.140

I mention that profile which I'm using already but although its opening in guest mode.
and I want that because in that profile I logged in of my accounts, preloaded things and histories too, that I want to access from that.